# Laravel Package Migration add column to existing App Migration in Database

Tags: laravel-5, migration, package

I'm creating a Laravel Package that will migrate / add a column to an already existing App Migration that was migrated prior to package being installed.

Is there any best methods for setting something like this up? And if so, how do you manage reset/refresh migrations from App and Package.

OR

Is it better to keep them both separate in that the Package Migration overrides all migrations that the App Migration would have done.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its always better to keep the column modifications in a separate migration unless and until0l you are so sure that your package is not used anywhere as of now. For existing installations it may cause problem with migration/rollback if you modify the existing migration. So i would recommend going with a new migration for column changes